# PLL configuration on SYSBIOS for TMS320F2812 does not work

Tags: rtos, texas-instruments, sysbios

I am currently trying to use SYS/BIOS 6.37.5.35 with xdctools version 3.25.6.96 with a F2812 platform.

The issue I am having is when I try to set up PLL configuration I get a warning saying

> PLL type is not assigned, so the Boot module will not configure PLL

This because of the following code in Platform.xs

```
if (this.deviceName.match(/2837/) || this.deviceName.match(/2807/)) {
    var Boot = xdc.useModule('ti.catalog.c2800.initF2837x.Boot');

    Boot.configureClocks = true;
}
else {
    var Boot = xdc.useModule('ti.catalog.c2800.init.Boot');

    Boot.disableWatchdog = true;
    Boot.configurePll = true;
    Boot.pllcrDIV = 10;
    Boot.pllstsDIVSEL = 2;


    /*
     * Set the Boot.pllType based on device name.  We set pllType
     * to undefined for the devices that we don't support.
     */
    if (this.deviceName.match(/2802[0-9]/) ||
        this.deviceName.match(/2803[0-9]/) ||
        this.deviceName.match(/2805[0-9]/) ||
        this.deviceName.match(/2806[0-9]/)) {
        Boot.pllType = Boot.Type_2802x_2803x_2806x;
    }
    else if (this.deviceName.match(/2823[0-9]/) ||
        this.deviceName.match(/2833[0-9]/)) {
        Boot.pllType = Boot.Type_282xx_283xx;
    }
    else if (this.deviceName.match(/2834[0-9]/)) {
        Boot.pllType = Boot.Type_2834x;
    }
    else { 
        Boot.configurePll = false;    /* do not set up PLL */
        Boot.pllType = undefined;     /* unknown device */

        /* if get here the PLL type is not assigned, throw warning ... */
        this.$module.$logWarning("The PLL type is not assigned, so the Boot"
            + " module will not configure the PLL.", this);
    }
}
```

Does this mean PLL configuration is not supported for 2812 in sys/bios?

Thanks & Regards,

Nikhil Kotian.

Answer (score 0):

I found in the documentation that the PLL cannot be configured for 2812 on SYS/BIOS. Therefore, the PLL needs to be configured by setting the PLLCR register.